# Illegal key size: possibly you need to install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for your JRE

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, java-7

I am using jruby with rails . I have installed JDK7 on my machine. Whenever I start my rails server and try to run my app I am getting error as `"Illegal key size: possibly you need to install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for your JRE"`

I searched on the google and found that I have to download JDK-7 security policy files. So I downloaded these file from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)  and put these files into my java directory path `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security"` . I thought this will resolve my problem but still I am getting same error.

while pasting files in the java's security folder i am getting alert box with information as `"you will need to provide administration permission to copy this folder"`. i cliked on continue button of alert box and file got copied.

I must be missing something.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

i created one file config/initializers/unlimited_strength_cryptography.rb with below content and it worked

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java' # Allows the application to work with other Rubies if not JRuby
  require 'java'
  java_import 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

  begin
    security_class = java.lang.Class.for_name('javax.crypto.JceSecurity')
    restricted_field = security_class.get_declared_field('isRestricted')
    restricted_field.accessible = true
    restricted_field.set nil, false
  rescue ClassNotFoundException => e
    # Handle Mac Java, etc not having this configuration setting
    $stderr.print "Java told me: #{e}n"
  end
end
```